# Reduce spacing below near figure with wrapping text around

Tags: formatting, wrapfigure

I have problems with formatting the figure in wrapped text in such a way that it doesn't take up excessively much of the space below it. Any help?

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{rO}{0.25\textwidth}
\caption{ 6 DOF}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/FigureName.png}
\label{fig:OC4_6DOF}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which we can test as it is. Try to replace `\begin{wrapfigure}{rO}{0.25\textwidth}` with `\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{r}{0.35\textwidth}`.

Comment: Wrapfig assumes every line is \baselineskip apart and the \subsection title is considered to be one line of text.  There may also be a problem wrt \@afterheading, althougn I believe wrapfig now redefines \@afterheading to leave \everypar alone.